# How to interpret Einstein's Field equations for 1+0 dimension $x$ in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, geodesics

The Einstein field equation for our $3+1$ spacetime dimensions is $$
R_{\mu \nu} - {1 \over 2} g_{\mu \nu} R + \Lambda g_{\mu \nu} = \frac{8  \pi G}{c^4} T_{\mu \nu}
$$

I am learning to navigate through this equation and would appreciate some help in interpreting the Einstein field equation in the trivial 1+0 dimension case, please. Let us consider only the $x$ space dimension, and no time dimension in this question.

I have some questions regarding the form of the equation in this **1+0 dimensional** case, as follows:

1. What is the form of the **Ricci curvature** $$R_{\mu \nu}$$ in one dimension. Is it a 1x1 matrix, ie. it is a scalar? Is its value always zero?
2. Is the value of the **Ricci scalar** $$R$$ always equal to zero in one dimension?
3. What is the form of the **metric tensor** $$g_{\mu \nu}$$ for one dimension? Is it just a scalar?
4. What is the form of the **stress-energy-momentum tensor** $$T_{\mu \nu}$$ in one dimension? Is it a scalar?

What can generally be interpreted from this equation in the 1 dimensional case? What information can be obtain from this equation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a $1$-dimensional manifold the Riemann tensor's only component is $R_{0000}=0$ by the tensor's symmetries, so $R_{\mu\nu}=0,\,R=0$. The EFE simplifies to $\Lambda g_{00}=\kappa T_{00}$. The two sides are still not scalar-valued, as they depend on the chosen coordinate system viz. $ds^2=g_{00}(dx^0)^2$.

Comment: @J G thanks for answering! From g_xx = T_xx, the way I understand it T_xx is the pressure at this instant snapshot of an object, say a marble in a small pipe. If T_xx is negative, the marble would want to travel left after the snapshot. If T_xx is positive, it wants to travel righter after the snapshot, is this a fair description? So this is akin to acceleration over "time", if time were to exist?